# Problems with upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu

I, too, recently tried to upgrade to 10.10 and got the error message "grub_xputs not found". I followed a suggestion "sudo grub-install..." The live CD ran and said "install completed. No errors." Upon rebooting, I now see a quick flash that looks like 'error" then the screen goes blank with the cursor flashing violently in the upper left hand corner of the screen. Nothing else happens. I will re-install 10.04 BUT I committed the gravest sin by not backing up my Desktop and other folders, i.e., music. Could someone tell me how to access my old 10.04 files [music, docs, etc] to save them if at all possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

boot up into a Ubuntu live cd and copy over any files to an external hd or usb dongle.